# Identity Column Issue in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have table 'Workflow' which has workflowid as identity column and also it is a primary key.

Problem is, lets say if i have 500 records and i have deleted record for workflowid = 300

then if i am trying to insert new records into table its taking identity value as 301 and here it is giving duplicate key error which is obvious.

I am not able to understood why it is taking deleted row workflowid + 1, instead of taking total rows(500) + 1, New identity should be 501.

Comment: Can you show insert query?

Comment: That is how SQL Server works. Actually this way of behaviour is better since it guarantees that records have unique Id-s.

Comment: It's true what @Anar said but it shouldn't go for 301 which is already occupied instead it should go to `MAX(id) + 1` also @Rohit please show us your insert qry + delete qry.

Comment: @Dan.Below is the insert query                                   INSERT INTO ATS_Workflow_Lang
   (
    LanguageID,Summary,Description
   )
   VALUES
   (
    1,'Summary','Description'
   )